# v5 special method `New` conflicts with static methods `New`

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

PowerShell v5 comes with a new feature. Instead of old fashioned creation of an object

```
New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
```

it is possible to use the new syntax

```
[System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
```

The new syntax introduces a problem though. If a class has a static method
`New` then it cannot be called directly anymore. It looks like PowerShell
thinks we are about to call a constructor, not this static method.

My real problem case cannot be explained in here so I use an existing class
just as an example.

This code works in PowerShell v4

```
[System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::New([psobject])
```

It calls the static method `New` and creates an expression.

In v5 it fails

```
Cannot find an overload for "new" and the argument count: "1".
At line:1 char:5
+     [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::New([psobject])
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

The question is how do we call static methods `New` in PowerShell v5?

Comment: Post it as an answer, I will accept it if there is nothing better. But this is already good. Thank you.

Comment: The second is "better", it also works v2.

Comment: PerSerAl's answer is better, but if needed you can also use reflection to invoke methods. In fact you can use reflection to invoke arbitrary constructors, even non-public constructors. This is true for other methods as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell call constructor when `new` is constant string token, and not when method name defined by expression. So you can use following workaround:

```
$New='New'
[System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::$New([psobject])
# or
[System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::('New')([psobject])
# or
[System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::{New}([psobject])
```

Also, if your does not use parenthesis after `New`, then PowerShell return `PSMethod` object to you, and you can use its `Invoke` method to invoke it.

```
[System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::New.Invoke([psobject])
```